# How is this JAX-RS webservice working?

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I'm going over few pieces of code and came across something like this

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON , MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public Response getMedia(
        @HeaderParam("X-META") String metaToken,
        @QueryParam("provider") String provider, MultivaluedMap<String, String> formContext ,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
    Map<String, String> context = APIUtils.buildContext(formContext);
    return getMediaInternal(metaToken, provider, context, uriInfo);
}
```

I know that Annotated vars are injected by jersey but I'm clueless as how the formContext is being injected. It's not annotated. What all values are put in here by jersey ? All the post parameters ? Whats a general rule to deduce whats being populated when not annotated ? Any pointers to reference material or a brief description of whats happening here is helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Jersey User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e1810), it seems like jersey will inject the MultiValuedMap<> type on a @POST request because form parameters are part of the message entity. This is the example:

```
Example 3.13. Obtaining general map of form parameters

@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public void post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
    // Store the message
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Somehow missed that part of the documentation.